# Чем заменить setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Имеется rest запрос в цикле и ожидание setTimeout. В примере установлен таймаут в 1000мс, хотелось бы уменьшить это время, так как количество итераций может быть большим. Если установить таймаут меньше (200, 100мс), бывает не успевает вытянуть значение из ответа, запинается, появляются ошибки, использую Postman. Есть ли способ ожидания выполнения запроса перед отправкой следующего? Пробовал Async/await но не разобрался с его работой...

```
var ArrCityName = [];
var Itteration = 0
var myFunc01 = function () {
const createRequest = {
  url: 'http://ufo-api.herokuapp.com/api/sightings/search?limit=200',
  method: 'GET',
  header: {},
    }
var myfunc02 = function () {
   pm.sendRequest(createRequest, function (err, request) { pm.collectionVariables.set("s", request.json().sightings[Itteration].city),Itteration++,  ArrCityName.push(pm.collectionVariables.get('s'))});
};
  myfunc02();
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (Itteration < 200 && ArrCityName.length == Itteration) {
      myFunc01()
  }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Просто запускайте setTimeout в момент получения ответа на запрос

Comment: Можно использовать fetch с asinc/await, либо просто чейнить следующий запрос с then

Comment: https://youtu.be/SHiUyM_fFME посмотрите и https://youtu.be/eKCD9djJQKc

Comment: "Просто запускайте setTimeout в момент получения ответа на запрос " - Да такой способ работает, но минимальное время между запросами ~200мс, если устанавливать более меньшее, скорость не меняется, в моем примере получалось ставить 30мс, но в таком случае, не всегда все запросы успешны. Имеется ли еще способ ускорить данный процесс?

Comment: Запускайте их параллельно. Почему у вас поиск зависит от соседних запросов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запускать таймаут в надежде, что он сработает после прилетевшего ответа - изначально неверный подход. Мало-ли из-за чего он может задержаться. Если всё нужно выполнять последовательно, пробуйте так:

```
let arrCityName = [];
let i = 0, limit = 200;

loop();

function loop() {
  const createRequest = {
    url: 'http://ufo-api.herokuapp.com/api/sightings/search?limit=200',
    method: 'GET',
    header: {},
  }

  pm.sendRequest(createRequest, function(err, request) {
    if (err) {
      console.warn("Bubu!!!");
      return;
    }

    pm.collectionVariables.set("s", request.json().sightings[i].city);
    arrCityName.push(pm.collectionVariables.get('s'));
    // Получил, обработал данные...

    if (++i < limit) {
      console.log(i + "...");
      loop(); // Только потом пойдет на следующий запрос.
    } else {
      console.log("done.", "\n", arrCityName);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение с помощью Fetch + Async/Await. Плюс пришлось подтянуть прокси.

```js
const cityNames = [];

const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const requestUrl = 'https://ufo-api.herokuapp.com/api/sightings/search?limit=200';
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {},
}

async function getCityNames() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(proxyUrl + requestUrl, requestOptions);
        const result = await response.json();
        return result.sightings.map(({ city }) => city);
    } catch(error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const names = await getCityNames();
        cityNames.push(names);
        const elements = names.map(name => `<li>${name}</li>`);
        list.innerHTML = elements.join('');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
})();
```

```html
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Comment: Postman, к сожалению, не поддерживает метод Fetch, буду благодарен если приведете пример без Fetch. Спасибо